# How to know all async/await completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to the async-programming, and trying to write some testing code to see what can I do with it.

below is my testing console app code, calling an async method, which will post some existing .docx file to my web api and convert to pdf.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //async testing - 5 files batch
        Console.WriteLine("Job Start:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var filestream = File.Open(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() +@".docx", FileMode.Open);

            //delegate
            Action act = async () =>
            {
                await test(filestream, i.ToString());
                filestream.Dispose();
            };

            act();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

and the method:

```
    static async Task<int> test(FileStream fs, string id)
    {
        var content = new StreamContent(fs);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        //post to web api
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:50348/PDFConvert/Convert?name=" + id, content);

        var ts = DateTime.Now - startTime;

        Console.WriteLine("Time Cost: " + ts.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds, " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", ""));

        client.Dispose();
        return 0;

    }
```

It works so far, but one issue is the "End." printed right after "Job Start:" on the console window, and then those await outputs.

So my question are:
1. How to print the "End" message after all async/await finished?
2. Not sure if it's the best practice, so any suggestion to existing code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never do `async void` unless you are writing a event handler and if you force it to be a `Action` delegate that is causing a `async void` delegate.

Change your delegate to be a `Func<Task>` then you can take the array of tasks and do a `WaitAll` on them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //async testing - 5 files batch
    Console.WriteLine("Job Start:");

    var tasks = new Task[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var filestream = File.Open(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() +@".docx", FileMode.Open);

        //Moved i.ToString() out of the delegate to fix a potential bug with variable capture.
        var stringToPrint = i.ToString()

        //delegate
        Func<Task> act = async () =>
        {
            await test(filestream, stringToPrint);
            filestream.Dispose();
        };

        var task = act();
        tasks[i] = task;
    }

    //In a non console program you will likely want to do "await Task.WhenAll(tasks);" instead.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine("End.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm new to the async-programming

I suggest my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) followed by my [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article.

Don't use `async` lambdas with `Action` delegate types; that results in an `async void` method. One of the drawbacks to `async void` methods is that you can't easily tell when they complete.

Async doesn't mesh naturally with Console apps. You can block the main thread on asynchronous code, but this is not a good pattern to use in any kind of other application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Job Start:");

  MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  Console.WriteLine("End.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    using (var filestream = File.Open(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() +@".docx", FileMode.Open))
      await test(filestream, i.ToString());
  }
}
```

**Update due to comment**:

Since you want to run your tasks concurrently, you should follow the guidance in my [`async` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
static async Task MainAsync()
{
  var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(TestFilesAsync).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task TestFilesAsync(int i)
{
  using (var filestream = File.Open(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() +@".docx", FileMode.Open))
    await test(filestream, i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works at the 'End' part but arise another issue: tasks run one by one, not in parallel. I got your idea that console apps is not a good example to test so I'll try to write something in winforms.

Comment: @blk25t: I updated the answer for your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async lambda inside the Linq Select method to iterate your task list and wait for them to complete

```
   var list = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select (
          async i => {
                var filestream = File.Open(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() +@".docx", FileMode.Open);
                await test(filestream, i.ToString());
                filestream.Dispose();
                }
     );
    Task.WaitAll (list.ToArray ());
```

If it wasn't a Console app but an async context, you could have used a `WhenAll` instead of `WaitAll`.